# how to grab the not equal row from joined table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have two tables as following

> user_job_applied

[image: user_job_applied]

> company_viewed_user

[image: company_viewed_user]

i want to take rows which are not in company_viewed_user table for relevant job_id in user_job_applied table.
i wrote the following query for it but it's not grabbed

```
SELECT
    `user_job_applied`.user_id
FROM
    `user_job_applied`
LEFT JOIN 
    `company_viewed_user` 
ON 
    `company_viewed_user`.user_id ON `company_viewed_user`.user_id = `user_job_applied`.user_id                               
WHERE
    `company_viewed_user`.user_id IS NULL AND
    `company_viewed_user`.emp_id IN (SELECT user_id 
                                     FROM company_user 
                                     WHERE company_id='1') 
AND
    `user_job_applied`.job_id = '1';
```

The output should be as following
[image]

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` doesn't seen to join on anything, shouldn't it be `ON company_viewed_user.user_id=user_job_applied.user_id`?

Comment: why did you tag php??

Comment: let's see there is a condition in left join

Comment: i tagged because of some people may be interest even they are ony involving php

Comment: can you say that why we want to shift that condition part from wher clause to left join??

Comment: There's no need for a subquery here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

want to move emp_id condition to left join statement from in where clause

```
SELECT
`user_job_applied`.user_id
FROM
`user_job_applied`
LEFT JOIN `company_viewed_user` ON `company_viewed_user`.user_id = `user_job_applied`.user_id AND 
                                                                `company_viewed_user`.emp_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM company_user WHERE company_id='1')                             
WHERE
`company_viewed_user`.user_id IS NULL AND                        
`user_job_applied`.job_id = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
SELECT uja.user_id 
FROM `user_job_applied` AS uja 
LEFT JOIN `company_viewed_user` AS cvu ON cvu.user_id = uja.user_id                             
WHERE cvu.user_id IS NULL;
```

If you want to add any other filter then you can include your own or let me know.

**Added new conditions**

```
SELECT uja.user_id 
FROM `user_job_applied` AS uja 
JOIN company_user AS cu ON cu.user_id=uja.emp_id 
LEFT JOIN `company_viewed_user` AS cvu ON cvu.user_id = uja.user_id                             
WHERE uja.job_id=1 AND cu.company_id=1 AND cvu.user_id IS NULL;
```

Note: If job_id and company_id is not Int type then enclosed in quotes.

Comment: i also posted code like you are saying.. but it's not give the result

Comment: plz execute once and check results, hope you will get desired results.

Comment: without emp_id condition it's working..with emp_id the query is like following answer post.

Comment: in your post there is no any clue of emp_id, please let me know what do you want to achieve based on emp_id and this table structure etc.

Comment: yah i want to get the data for logged in employer who should be same company.that's a thing i checked there